# Buck Converter Design Issue: Load voltage capped at ~9V the Vin is max 24V

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice, buck, mosfet-driver, teensy

I'm very stuck and I've run out of solutions.  I designed a buck converter in ltspice which I then physically made.  It worked decently at high voltages, but at low voltages, the gate signal just becomes warped and alot of heat is dissipated.  That's not even the main issue, the issue is that the circuit only works if I'm using an oscilloscope and scope probe to monitor the signal on my microcontroller which provides the pulse signal (in this case a teensy 3.5).

I've attached an updated schematic of my simulation:

[image: Current theoretical simulation]

The DC-DC converter that I would use physically is much simpler than the LTM8057.  I'm simulating with the LTM8057 to see if the problems I was having with my buck converter was DC-DC converter related or otherwise.

I've narrowed down the issue to the gate driver (TC4432).  The thing has no reference voltage and then uses my Teensy/scope probe has a high impedence to ground.  This causes my Teensy's to blow up (I've fried 3 so far).  Reading some online sources suggests that the gate driver should have a reference to the source side of the circuit (on the right of the MOSFET).  My idea was to just link the Vout- of the LTM8057 to the right side (source) of the MOSFET.  But no matter what I do, the circuit doesn't run.  It only runs in the above configuration where even at maximum duty cycle, I only get 9 V on the load:

[image: Voltage across 10 ohm load]

I have no idea what to do now.  I don't want to waste time soldering another circuit.  The last circuit I built confirmed that there was something badly wrong:

[image: Efficiency of most recent physical buck converter]

At lower duty cycles, it becomes horribly inefficient.  It only worked at higher duty cycles because I was scope probing the Teensy to monitor the output PWM signal.  I thought it was a common ground issue, but rearranging my grounds didn't work.  So I've fallen back to simulations again.

So finally my question is: **In the above simulation, how do I get full range of voltage across my 10 ohm load?**.  Then I can try to recreate it physically.

Thanks!

**EDIT: If the gate needs to be driven with a higher side voltage more than or equal to the source (24 V), then why does this following schematic work?**
[image: The isolated DC-DC converter has been swapped out with an isolated pulsed supply with its negative output to the source. This works even though the voltage is 12 V.]

Comment: Shouldn't Vout- of the dcdc converter and the GND pin of your driver along with decoupling caps be connected to the source pin of your MOSFET? If not the gate voltage depends on the output voltage. Also, the PWM signal would have to be floating as well.

Comment: Link to the FET driver datasheet, but I think ocspro has it. Your 12V isolated supply isn't isolated because you grounded it.  As a result your Vout is limited to 12V - Vgs.

Comment: TC4432 is normally an 8-pin package part (at least the one from Microchip). You have a N-channel MOSFET in the high-side of your 24V buck circuit with a V_GS threshold of 10V, meaning you need 34V on the gate to turn it ON. You do not have a 34V supply in your circuit and as such the MOSFET is 'pinching off' the input DC. You need to rethink your circuit somewhat.

Comment: @ocspro I tried that (connecting both vout- and pin 4 of my gate driver to the source side of my MOSFET), I either get an error or the source side is short circuited to ground.  Could you explain abit more what you mean? And the decoupling capacitors are on the Vdd side (pin 3) of my gate driver.  Why are they involved in this?

Comment: @AdamLawrence The LTSpice model of the TC4432 is a 5 pin, Input (1), Output (2), Positive Supply (3), Negative Supply (4)  and UV_Lockout (5).  I'm new to the power electronics scene.  Can rethinking my circuit be as simple as using a P-channel MOSFET instead?

Comment: P-channel MOSFETs are often used in buck converters for that very reason. However they tend to have higher conduction losses vs. N-channel MOSFETs.

Comment: @AdamLawrence I can accept a slightly lower efficiency in return for something that works without nuance.  Should I make a redesign with a P-Channel Mosfet?  Because in the other answers, I'm not quite following the whole "Vout- and GND should be connected with the source" instructions.  I tried that and it didn't work.  But I read that with P-Channel MOSFET you do not need a high voltage on the gate.

Comment: Your existing design cannot work without some form of high-side supply which can drive the series-pass N-channel MOSFET gate sufficiently higher than the source. Fixing your grounding does not fix this fundamental flaw in the circuit. P-channel can work with a single-supply voltage like you have, as long as the driver is powered from the same rail feeding the drain of the MOSFET (i.e. not the low-voltage supply of the microcontroller).

Comment: @AdamLawrence Hi, please be patient with me.  I need to understand this.  I edited my opening post with a new image.  I changed the DC-DC converter and swapped it for a generic 12V pulsed supply, with the negative output to the source of my N-channel MOSFET.  This opens and shuts the gate perfectly with very low switching losses in the simulation.  Why does this work even though its not a "high side" supply?  This was infact the simulation that I based my physical buck converter on, but the buck converter had those weird issues any way.  I hope you can see why I'm so confused.

Comment: The low side of your pulsed source is referenced to the source of the MOSFET. You are applying 12V from gate-to-source and the MOSFET turns on. In your previous circuit, you had the low side of the gate driver to ground, not to the source of the MOSFET. Do you see the difference now? Your pulsed supply *is* "high-side" since its return is not tied to output return. Switching power is sometimes spooky. I've been in that industry for around 20 years now - things aren't always intuitive. (Try disconnecting the pulsed source low side from the MOSFET source and try tying it to ground...)

Answer (score 2):

To turn off that FET, the gate driver Vout needs to be up at 24 volts.

This circuit does not provide that.

Comment: But the MOSFET I chose can be driven at 12 V, that's why the signal of the gate driver is around 12 V.

Comment: He's referenceing the driver to the source, so it's fine. (I'm talking about the last spice schematic shown)